# URL is getting appended again in URL on clicking any link Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, redirect

When I click any link or use redirect it always appends the URL in the URL.Like before clicking my URL looks like http://plushcash-chat.backtrak.co/
But when I click the visible here URL becomes: http://plushcash-chat.backtrak.co%2C%20plushcash-chat.backtrak.co/

My Routes Look Like:

```
root 'chatrooms#index'
  resources :chatrooms do
    collection do
      get :check_username
    end
  end

  resources :messages
  get '/signed_out', to: 'welcome#sign_out_user'
  get "leaderboards/top_affiliates"
  get '/chat', to: 'welcome#chat'
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

Controller Code:
Registration Controller

```
build_resource(configure_sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :alert, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
    cookies.signed[:user_id] = current_user.id
```

It happens in all controllers. I am using:

```
if current_user.present?
      @chatroom = Chatroom.new(chatroom_params)
      if @chatroom.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @chatroom }
          format.js
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          flash[:notice] = {error: ["a chatroom with this topic already exists"]}
          format.html { redirect_to new_chatroom_path }
          format.js { render template: 'chatrooms/chatroom_error.js.erb'} 
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
```

Comment: paste you controller code

Comment: and view, specially form. routes look good. when I submitted the form, it redirected to that wrong url but when I hit the homepage again, my session was continued.

Comment: puneet18 i pasted the controller code above in my question after editing it.

Comment: all this code is irrelevant. We need the view code (the one with the links).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing in your views - there is a ", " somewhere.

As you can check for yourself in your browser console:

```
> decodeURIComponent("%2C%20")
> ", "
```

Just check the exact part in your view, where the link is set.